# How to access an association in a custom validation method in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Let's say I have a model with two has_one associations with the same class because I know I need exactly two. I want to write a custom validation method that checks these associations. Say the jersey class has two strings, `primaryColor` and `secondaryColor`.

```
class SportsTeam < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :homeJersey, class_name: 'Jersey', foreign_key: 'home_color'
  has_one :awayJersey, class_name: 'Jersey', foreign_key: 'away_color'
  validates :check_colors_do_not_reused

  def check_colors_are_not_reused
      # if :homeJersey.primaryColor == :awayJersey.secondaryColor
      #    errors.add(:awayJersey.secondaryColor, "change color of one of the jerseys")
      # end
  end
```

end

I am confused as to how to access the association's fields, because :homeJersey is a symbol. Do I have to query it within the helper?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be just the following, because Rails generates methods named by the symbol:

```
def check_colors_are_not_reused
  if homeJersey.primaryColor == awayJersey.secondaryColor
    errors.add(:awayJersey.secondaryColor, "change color of one of the jerseys")
  end
end
```

Beside that: The naming conventions in Ruby and Rails are to name things with underscores instead of using camelcase. I recommend to rename your associations and methods so that you have calls like: `home_jersey.primary_color`.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up about the camelcase